# What is the equivalent of printf for write in C?

Tags: c, printf

How do you do this:

```
printf("I would like %d tomatoes", numTomatoes);
```

with:

```
write(STDOUT, "HOW?", 4);
```

Is there some type of pre-processing that makes it all a char array and then I can find the length and print it out?

Context: I need to use write instead of printf inside of signal handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a formatted string you can use `sprintf/snprintf`;

```
char buffer[0x1000];
size_t length = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "I would like %d tomatoes", numTomatoes);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, length);
```

**Edit:** If you are bothered by the large buffer size then you can (in modern C99) do the following to determine the necessary buffer size first:

```
size_t length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "I would like %d tomatoes", numTomatoes);
char buffer[length];
snprintf(buffer, length, "I would like %d tomatoes", numTomatoes);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, length);
```

Comment: For a signal handler, `char buffer[0x1000]` looks quite large.

Comment: If the string ever exceeds the buffer size, is there any way to check? Also like @chux said, would it use too much at any point even though 1000 chars is relatively small in today's computing.

Comment: @donkon you can check `length` against `sizeof(buffer)` if it is larger then `snprintf` has truncated the output. The second argument makes sure it does not write beyond the buffer. At that point you know how long the output will be, you can allocate a larger buffer and call `snprintf` again.

Comment: length can be greater than sizeof(buffer) - meaning extra chars were discarded.

Comment: @donkon In 2014 with embedded processing, where C is _very_ popular, `0x1000` can easily exceed the entire RAM space.

Comment: Suggest `int size = 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, ...`; "The snprintf function returns the number of characters that would have been written had n been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred."